# Tensorflow dynamic_rnn parameters meaning

Tags: tensorflow

I'm struggling to understand the cryptic RNN docs. Any help with the following will be greatly appreciated.

```
tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, sequence_length=None, initial_state=None, dtype=None, parallel_iterations=None, swap_memory=False, time_major=False, scope=None)
```

I'm struggling to understand how these parameters relate to the mathematical LSTM equations and RNN definition. Where is the cell unroll size? Is it defined by the 'max_time'  dimension of the inputs? Is the batch_size only a convenience for splitting long data or it's related to minibatch SGD? Is the output state passed across batches?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` takes in a batch (with the minibatch meaning) of unrelated sequences.

- `cell` is the actual cell that you want to use (LSTM, GRU,...)
- `inputs` has a shape of `batch_size x max_time x input_size` in which max_time is the number of steps in the longest sequence (but all sequences could be of the same length)
- `sequence_length` is a vector of size `batch_size` in which each element gives the length of each sequence in the batch (leave it as default if all your sequences are of the same size. **This parameter is the one that defines the cell unroll size.**

#### Hidden state handling

The usual way of handling hidden state is to define an initial state tensor before the `dynamic_rnn`, like this for instance :

```
hidden_state_in = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32) 
output, hidden_state_out = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, 
                                             inputs,
                                             initial_state=hidden_state_in,
                                             ...)
```

In the above snippet, both `hidden_state_in` and `hidden_state_out` have the same shape `[batch_size, ...]` (*the actual shape depends on the type of cell you use but the important thing is that the first dimension is the batch size*).

This way, `dynamic_rnn` has an initial hidden state for each sequence. **It will pass on the hidden state from time step to time step for each sequence in the `inputs` parameter on its own**, and `hidden_state_out` will contain the final output state for each sequence in the batch. No hidden state is passed between sequences of the same batch, but only between time steps of the same sequence.

#### When do I need to feed back the hidden state manually?

Usually, when you're training, every batch is unrelated so you don't have to feed back the hidden state when doing a `session.run(output)`.

However, if you're testing, and you need the output at each time step, (i.e. you have to do a `session.run()` at every time step) you'll want to evaluate and feed back the output hidden state using something like this :

```
output, hidden_state = sess.run([output, hidden_state_out],
                                feed_dict={hidden_state_in:hidden_state})
```

otherwise tensorflow will just use the default `cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)` at each time step which equates to reinitialising the hidden state at each time step.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful, I'm 95% there :) What's the conceptual meaning of the minibatches? The LSTM cell for example can exist just with its own state and can be trained with a single stream of data. I suppose this would happen with batch_size = 1. You state that they are unrelated sequences. What's the conceptual meaning of the minibatches? For training with minibatch SGD? For parallel efficient training?

Comment: That would indeed happen with batch_size = 1. The reason why we use batch training is because it makes training more stable. Updating your weights based on an average of gradients over your batch is more likely to move you in the right direction than by just updating based on the gradient of one sample.
Having a batch size larger than 1 usually only makes sense during the training phase.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation. I have a question thought. How can i explicitly control the value of the variable `batch_size` or implicitly infer it? Any directions on that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: This is a bit old, but how are you going to define the shape of the placeholder named `hidden_state_in` ?

Comment: This is correct but tensorflow does allow passing tensor objects in the feed_dict. So, be careful with it because hidden state from dynamic_rnn will be a tensor object.

Comment: Could you please explain the parameter `sequence_length`, how can I set a vector to this parameter? (I read the official API of function `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, but the corresponding explanation was too little)