# Difference of Pre-Padding and Post-Padding text when preprossing different text sizes for tf.nn.embedding_lookup

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, text-classification, word-embedding

I have seen two types of padding when feeding to embedding layers.

> **eg:**
>
> considering two sentences:
>
> word1 = "I am a dog person."
>
> word2 = "Krishni and Pradeepa both love cats."
>
> word1_int = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>
> word2_int = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
>
> padding both words to length = 8
>
> **padding method 1**(putting 0s at the beginning)
>
> word1_int = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>
> word2_int = [0,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
>
> **padding method 2**(putting 0s at the end)
>
> word1_int = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0]
>
> word2_int = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,0]

I am trying to do an **online** classification using the 20 news groups dataset. and I am currently using the 1st method to pad my text.

**Question**: Is there any advantage of using the 1st method over the other one in my implementation?

Thank you in advance!

My code is shown below:

```
from collections import Counter
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import matplotlib as mplt
mplt.use('agg') # Must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or pylab!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from string import punctuation
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')



def pre_process():
    newsgroups_data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))

    words = []
    temp_post_text = []
    print(len(newsgroups_data.data))

    for post in newsgroups_data.data:

        all_text = ''.join([text for text in post if text not in punctuation])
        all_text = all_text.split('\n')
        all_text = ''.join(all_text)
        temp_text = all_text.split(" ")

        for word in temp_text:
            if word.isalpha():
                temp_text[temp_text.index(word)] = word.lower()

        # temp_text = [word for word in temp_text if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
        temp_text = list(filter(None, temp_text))
        temp_text = ' '.join([i for i in temp_text if not i.isdigit()])
        words += temp_text.split(" ")
        temp_post_text.append(temp_text)

    # temp_post_text = list(filter(None, temp_post_text))

    dictionary = Counter(words)
    # deleting spaces
    # del dictionary[""]
    sorted_split_words = sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)
    vocab_to_int = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(sorted_split_words,1)}

    message_ints = []
    for message in temp_post_text:
        temp_message = message.split(" ")
        message_ints.append([vocab_to_int[i] for i in temp_message])


    # maximum message length = 6577

    # message_lens = Counter([len(x) for x in message_ints])AAA

    seq_length = 6577
    num_messages = len(temp_post_text)
    features = np.zeros([num_messages, seq_length], dtype=int)
    for i, row in enumerate(message_ints):
        print(features[i, -len(row):])
        features[i, -len(row):] = np.array(row)[:seq_length]
        print(features[i, -len(row):])

    lb = LabelBinarizer()
    lbl = newsgroups_data.target
    labels = np.reshape(lbl, [-1])
    labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)

    return features, labels, len(sorted_split_words)+1


def get_batches(x, y, batch_size=1):
    for ii in range(0, len(y), batch_size):
        yield x[ii:ii + batch_size], y[ii:ii + batch_size]


def plot(noOfWrongPred, dataPoints):
    font_size = 14
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=100,figsize=(10, 6))
    mplt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font_size})
    plt.title("Distribution of wrong predictions", fontsize=font_size)
    plt.ylabel('Error rate', fontsize=font_size)
    plt.xlabel('Number of data points', fontsize=font_size)

    plt.plot(dataPoints, noOfWrongPred, label='Prediction', color='blue', linewidth=1.8)
    # plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=14)

    plt.savefig('distribution of wrong predictions.png')
    # plt.show()



def train_test():
    features, labels, n_words = pre_process()

    print(features.shape)
    print(labels.shape)

    # Defining Hyperparameters

    lstm_layers = 1
    batch_size = 1
    lstm_size = 200
    learning_rate = 0.01

    # --------------placeholders-------------------------------------

    # Create the graph object
    graph = tf.Graph()
    # Add nodes to the graph
    with graph.as_default():

        tf.set_random_seed(1)

        inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="inputs")
        # labels_ = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.int32)
        labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None], name="labels")

        # output_keep_prob is the dropout added to the RNN's outputs, the dropout will have no effect on the calculation of the subsequent states.
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")

        # Size of the embedding vectors (number of units in the embedding layer)
        embed_size = 300

        # generating random values from a uniform distribution (minval included and maxval excluded)
        embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_words, embed_size), -1, 1),trainable=True)
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs_)

        print(embedding.shape)
        print(embed.shape)
        print(embed[0])

        # Your basic LSTM cell
        lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)


        # Add dropout to the cell
        drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

        # Stack up multiple LSTM layers, for deep learning
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop] * lstm_layers)

        # Getting an initial state of all zeros
        initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)

        # hidden layer
        hidden = tf.layers.dense(outputs[:, -1], units=25, activation=tf.nn.relu)

        print(hidden.shape)

        logit = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden, num_outputs=20, activation_fn=None)

        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, labels=labels_))

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # ----------------------------online training-----------------------------------------

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        tf.set_random_seed(1)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        iteration = 1
        state = sess.run(initial_state)
        wrongPred = 0
        noOfWrongPreds = []
        dataPoints = []

        for ii, (x, y) in enumerate(get_batches(features, labels, batch_size), 1):

            feed = {inputs_: x,
                    labels_: y,
                    keep_prob: 0.5,
                    initial_state: state}

            embedzz = sess.run(embedding, feed_dict=feed)

            print(embedzz)


            predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logit).eval(feed_dict=feed)

            print("----------------------------------------------------------")
            print("Iteration: {}".format(iteration))

            isequal = np.equal(np.argmax(predictions[0], 0), np.argmax(y[0], 0))

            print(np.argmax(predictions[0], 0))
            print(np.argmax(y[0], 0))

            if not (isequal):
                wrongPred += 1

            print("nummber of wrong preds: ",wrongPred)

            if iteration%50 == 0:
                noOfWrongPreds.append(wrongPred/iteration)
                dataPoints.append(iteration)

            loss, states, _ = sess.run([cost, final_state, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)

            print("Train loss: {:.3f}".format(loss))
            iteration += 1

        saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/sentiment.ckpt")
        errorRate = wrongPred / len(labels)
        print("ERRORS: ", wrongPred)
        print("ERROR RATE: ", errorRate)
        plot(noOfWrongPreds, dataPoints)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_test()
```

This is the code sample that I am using to pad all the sentences.

```
  seq_length = 6577
  num_messages = len(temp_post_text)
    features = np.zeros([num_messages, seq_length], dtype=int)
    for i, row in enumerate(message_ints):
        print(features[i, -len(row):])
        features[i, -len(row):] = np.array(row)[:seq_length]
        print(features[i, -len(row):])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, when we use LSTM or RNN's, we use the final output or the hidden state and pass it along to make predictions. You are also doing the same thing as seen in this line:

```
logit = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden, num_outputs=20, activation_fn=None)
```

Here the two methods of padding get differentiated. If you use the 2nd method of padding, post-padding, then the final hidden state would get flushed out as mostly it will be `0`, whereas by using the 1st method, we make sure that the hidden state output is correct.

Comment: One more small question, In the 'tf.nn.dynamic_rnn' I am putting the attribute 'sequence_length' in order eliminate the influence of the padded 0s to the training. So this can only be done when the padding is done as post padding. But now since the 0s are gone  the final hidden state will not get flushed right?

Comment: You are correct, the sequence length parameter is used like this. Check this answer for more clarification - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469779/how-to-handle-padding-when-using-sequence-length-parameter-in-tensorflow-dynamic?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Remember the problem that we have with RNN, the vanishing gradient. So if you are using Pre-padding, then there are actual values to be remembered by the RNN at the last and for post-padding, the actual values are at the start. Hence, if there is long padding, there is a high chance that the model might forget what the actual values are that need to be remembered and the model might not perform well.
So, I personally suggest you to use pre-padding rather than post-padding.